# Intuitive explanation of the Dirichlet function and rationality

Tags: functions, irrational-numbers, rational-numbers

The Dirichlet function is defined by $f(x)=\begin{cases} c &\text{ if } x\in \mathbb{Q}\\d &\text{ if } x\notin \mathbb{Q}.\end{cases}, c\neq d$

See [MathWorld's page](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DirichletFunction.html) for the full definition.

One of the properties of the Dirichlet function is that it is discontinuous everywhere, which means that its graph would look like this:
 [image]

**If I understand correctly, then it would imply the following:**

If $x$ is rational, then $\lim_{h\to0} x+h$ would be irrational. And conversely, if $x$ is irrational, then $\lim_{h\to0} x+h$ would be rational.

I'm having an extremely hard time grasping this concept.

For example, if $x$ cannot be written as $\frac{a}{b}$, then why can $\lim_{h\to0} x+h$ be written as $\frac{a}{b}$ ?

If someone could intuitively explain this, then it would be much appreciated.
Also, if I do not understand the Dirichlet function correctly, then please also explain why.

**EDIT**
Another example:
If there are two rational numbers arbitrarily close together, wouldn't there be another rational number in between them? And if so, wouldn't it make the Dirichlet function continuous at that point?

Comment: You have reproduced a representation of $ f_M$ which is a different function from $ f$.

Comment: Can you please explain why

Comment: Don't bother about those countable many non- zero values, they don't matter.  It's just dirt.  The function does equal zero except for some countable values, and they don't count.

Comment: $\lim_{x\to c}f(x)$ _does not exist_ for any $c$. This is because, for any $c$, there is both a sequence of rationals approaching it, and a sequence of irrationals approaching it.

Comment: By the way, $\lim_{h\to0}(x+h)$ is equal to $x$.

Answer (score 0):

$\mathbb{Q}$ is *dense* in $\mathbb{R}$, which means in this case that:

$$ \forall x,y \in \mathbb{R} \hspace{2mm} \text{with} \hspace{2mm} x < y \hspace{2mm} \exists r \in \mathbb{Q}: x < r < y $$

So, for two real (particularly irrational) numbers, there is **always** a rational number in between, no matter how close the two reals are to each other. So the Dirichlet function jumps from $c$ to $d$ and vice versa for every (arbitrarily small) iteration of $x$.

Here you can see a plot for $c=1$ and $d=0$: [German Wikipedia](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet-Funktion)

EDIT: Changes made, thanks to comment of LJL.

Comment: Can't you argue that for any two rational numbers, there is another rational number in between? And if there is, wouldn't it make the Dirichlet function continuous at that point?

Comment: Your definition is backwards. "$\mathbb{Q}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$" means that for all $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $x<y$, there exists $r \in \mathbb{Q}$ such that $x<r<y$.

Answer (score 0):

It may be easier to see if you use the sequence approach to continuity:

Pick an  $p\in \mathbb Q$ and from each neighborhood $B_{1/n}(p)$ choose an irrational number $x_{n}$. Then you get a sequence with the property that

$x_{n}\to p$ and $f(x_{n})=d\quad \forall n\in \mathbb N$.

Since $f(p)=c\neq d$, $f$ is not continuous at $p$.

Simlarly, if $x\in \mathbb P$, you can find a sequence of rationals $p_{n}$ converging to $x$, such that $f(p_{n})=c$ and then since $f(x)=d$, $f$ is not contiuous at $x$.

Comment: I am not very familiar with topological space, please explain how you get the property that xn→p? Why wouldn't xn→x(n+1) ?

Comment: @Paul: we've worked it so the neigborhoods--intervals containing $p$ are collapsing to $p$ itself. Each interval has width $2/n$ so as $n$ gets large the widths get small. Draw the picture to see what's going on. You do need to know what it means for a sequence to converge.  Note that the Axiom of Choice is what allows us to pick an arbitrary point from each interval.

Comment: Just to be clear, is it incorrect to say the following:

Comment: Pick an  $p\in \mathbb Q$ and from each neighborhood $B_{1/n}(p)$ choose an rational number $r_{n}$. Then you get a sequence with the property that 

$r_{n}\to p$ and $f(r_{n})=c\quad \forall n\in \mathbb N$. 

It is thus continuous at $p$.